# NumberFormat incorrect parse for non default locale in java

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting

NumberFormat is incorrectly parsing a number for locale other than the default en_US. For example parsing for fr_CA gives incorrect results.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("fr_CA"));
Number num = nf.parse("2.302,52");
```

Output is: `2.302`

Expected output: `2302,52` or `2302.52`

It is basically changing the value of this number from 2 thousands something to just 2 something, which is incorrect.

See the below screenshot for details:
[image]

What is going wrong I'm unable to identify, please help !

Comment: @Jens: do observe that the value is incorrect, it has to be 2302.52, internal representation can't change the value !

Comment: @Jens: since you've deleted your comment could you please mend your down vote as well.

Answer (score 1):

### **EDIT 1:**

I was able to use DecimalFormat to correctly parse non default locale values by setting the decimal and grouping separator as:

```
        /**
         * Testing DF parse
         */
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        Number num = df.parse("2.302,52"); // OUTPUT is: 2302.52 -> correctly parsed

        /**
         * Round off and format
         */
        double d = num.doubleValue();
        double roundedVal = Math.round(d); // OUTPUT is: 2303.0 -> correctly rounded off
        String localeAwareVlue = df.format(roundedVal); // OUTPUT is: 2.303 -> using correct grouping separator
        valueString = localeAwareVlue;
```

But I really want to be able to do this dynamically at run time without having to set the separators for each language/country combination I might receive. Please help with any suggestions.

### **EDIT 2:**

I ended up with the following final code to be able to dynamically parse and format localized values. This works for patterns like ###,###.## and ###.###,## - assumptions being -

1. there are always only 2 decimal places in the data received
2. decimal separator is either a comma or a period
3. grouping separator is either a period or a comma

   ```
   String localValue = args.get(0).toString();
   // String locale = args.get(1).toString();

   char decChar = localValue.charAt(localValue.length()-3);
   char grpChar = ',';
   if(decChar == ',') {
       grpChar = '.';
   }
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
   DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
   symbols.setDecimalSeparator(decChar);
   symbols.setGroupingSeparator(grpChar);
   df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

   Number parsedValue = 0;
   try {
       parsedValue = df.parse(localValue);
   }
   catch (ParseException pe) {
       pe.printStackTrace();
   }

   /**
    * Round off and format to localize
    */
   double roundedValue = Math.round(parsedValue.doubleValue());
   String localeAwareValue = df.format(roundedValue);


   // TODO - use Locale with nf instead of above method
   // currently facing issue with incorrect parse for non default locale
   /*
      NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale(locale));
      Number num = nf.parse(localValue);
   */
   ```

Needless to say I'm not satisfied with the solution, which is more of a workaround until I get a solution to the main problem - NumberFormat incorrect parse for non default locale. Therefore any hints, suggestions, solutions are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here,

1) You're creating the locale incorrectly. Use `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`.

2) The given number is invalid in both the default and Canadian locales. As per [ICU](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/fr-CA/index.html), in `fr_CA`, the grouping separator is empty, and the decimal separator is `,`.

As such, in your example, that uses the default locale, it treats `.` as a decimal separator and bails at `,`, where as in the correct locale it will bail at `.` and return simply `2`.

The *correct* way to write this number in `fr_CA` is `2302,52`

So, really, Java is correct, but your assumption on the format of this number is incorrect.